# Save disconnected object in entity framework 4

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

in EF1, i couldn't just update an object that was constructed (with the right id) outside the scope of the ObjectContext.

Is there a new way in EF4?

Can i just add it to the context `(context.AddOrder(order))` (where context is an instance of my ObjectContext) and 'it' sees that it has an id and updates it?

It's non-poco so my objects derive from `EntityObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Attach method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx) instead. It is designed for disconnected objects.

Comment: i'n not sure, i have a newly constructed object, and the attach method is for objects 'when the object has an entity key'. Do i have an entity key when i just set the properties of an object?

Comment: Here is a code snippet to attach: context.Orders.Attach(order);
context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(order, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
order.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 5):

If it's a brand new object then you should use either [**ObjectContext.AddObject**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.addobject.aspx) or **[ObjectSet.AddObject:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487277.aspx)**

The *AddObject* method is for adding newly created objects that do ***not*** exist in the database. The entity will get an automatically generated temporary *EntityKey* and its
EntityState will be set to *Added*.

On the other hand **[ObjectContext.Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx)** and [**ObjectSet.Attach**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487214.aspx) is used for entities that already ***exist*** in the database. Rather than setting the EntityState to Added, Attach results in an *Unchanged* EntityState, which means it has not changed since it was attached to the context. Objects that you are attaching are assumed to exist in the database.

For a more detailed discussion on this topic, please take a look at this post:

[*Entity Framework 4 - AddObject vs Attach*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920111/entity-framework-4-addobject-vs-attach)

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Employee Info Starter Kit](http://eisk.codeplex.com/), you can consider the code snippet as below:

```
public void UpdateEmployee(Employee updatedEmployee)
        {
            //attaching and making ready for parsistance
            if (updatedEmployee.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
                _DatabaseContext.Employees.Attach(updatedEmployee);
            _DatabaseContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(updatedEmployee, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
            _DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```