# Update in Entity Framework 6 without a roundtrip

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

In EF 4.1, when I wanted to update a record, I could avoid the roundtrip of loading it first by creating a new entity, setting the primary key, attaching it to the DBContext, then updating the field. Change tracking would ensure that only the fields I changed after attaching the entity would update. This method is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347086/how-to-update-an-entity-without-a-round-trip-ef-4). But now I'm trying it with EF 6.1 on an ASP.NET project, and find that it doesn't work.

```
var court_code = new System_Court();
court_code.UID = UID;
SHEntity.System_Court.Attach(court_code);
court_code.Deleted = true;
SHEntity.SaveChanges();
```

This would have worked previously, but now it gives me a validation error, saying I'm missing various required fields - which I am, but it shouldn't care since `Deleted` is the only record I want updated. But if I do it with a roundtrip, it works fine.

```
var court_code = SHEntity.System_Court.Where(w => w.UID == UID).First(); 
court_code.Deleted = true;
SHEntity.SaveChanges();
```

Is this something that has changed between EF 4 and EF 6? I see that EF 6 generates different looking entity classes than EF 4 did (EF 4 had a bunch of stuff like Entity Key, where as EF 6 looks like a simple POCO). Googling shows a number of changes between EF 4 and 5, but I don't see any mention about how to make this trick work now.

Update:
Looking at the sql executed by the second block of code, I see that just `Deleted` is being updated, as it should.. so is this some issue with creating the object and attaching it like that?

Comment: Have you tried setting the entity's state to `Modified` in the context?

Comment: In addition to comment of @Asad: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20451793/1803777

Comment: @Asad Looking at it in the debugger, I see that it attaches as `Unchanged` and then after I set Deleted to true, it becomes `Modified`, just like it should. It still seems to want to validate the unchanged fields though

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov That link has a lot of great info, but it didn't help me. I even tried setting the entire thing to `Unchanged` and then individually setting the Deleted property to `Modified` but I still got the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While coding I managed to stumble around the correct answer a few times before finally realizing that I was asking the wrong question. With the help of the comments, I learned about some EF 5 breaking changes involving change tracking, and that helped me realize that it was validation that I needed to disable.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871892/entity-framework-validation-with-partial-updates) for an explanation of it, but essentially what I needed was

```
SHEntity.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```