# Entity Framework: Shouldn't attaching the following entity throw an exception?

Tags: entity-framework-4

As far as I can tell, `EntityCollection.Attach` and `EntityReference.Attach` can only create relationships that already exists in the database. In other words, if `Address.EmployeeID == Employee.EmployeeID`, then the following code will work:

```
        Employee employee = context.Employees.First();
        Address address = context.Addresses.First();
        employee.Addresses.Attach(address);
```

But if `Address.EmployeeID != Employee.EmployeeID`, then the code will throw an exception:

```
        Employee employee = context.Employees.First();
        Address address = context.Addresses.First();
        employee.Addresses.Attach(address); // System.InvalidOperationException: A 
                                            // referential integrity constraint
                                            // violation occurred
```

But according to a code example taken from the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920111/entity-framework-4-addobject-vs-attach), `EntityCollection.Attach` and `EntityReference.Attach` can also be used to create a relationship that doesn't exist in a DB:

```
var existingPerson = ctx.Persons.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name = "Joe Bloggs" };
var myAddress = ctx.Addresses.First(a => a.PersonID != existingPerson.PersonID);
existingPerson.Addresses.Attach(myAddress);
// OR:
myAddress.PersonReference.Attach(existingPerson)
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

So am I correct in assuming that `EntityCollection.Attach` and `EntityReference.Attach` can only create relationships that already exists in the database, and as such code example taken from the other thread should throw an exception?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it's just a typing mistake or author has written something incomplete.

```
var existingPerson = ctx.Persons.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name = "Joe Bloggs" };
var myAddress = ctx.Addresses.First(a => a.PersonID == existingPerson.PersonID);
existingPerson.Addresses.Attach(myAddress);
// OR:
myAddress.PersonReference.Attach(existingPerson)
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You will get 50 points, but could you just answer me this so I can be completely sure: so I'm correct in assuming that EntityCollection.Attach and EntityReference.Attach can only create relationships that already exists in a database?