# entity framework update many to many relationship: virtual or not

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've been using EF4 (not code-first) since a year, so I'm not really an expert with it. 
I've a doubt in using many-to-many relationship regarding save n update.

I read somewhere on stackoverflow (i can't find the url anymore) that one solution - to update an existing many-to-many relation - is to not declare "virtual" property; but, if i do this way, the engine can't load dataas with easy loading.

Can you pls explain me the reason? Otherwire, could you please help me in finding some cool docs on this theme?

thx

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can update a many-to-many relationship this way (as an example which gives user 3 the role 5):

```
using (var context = new MyObjectContext())
{
    var user = context.Users.Single(u => u.UserId == 3);
    var role = context.Roles.Single(r => r.RoleId == 5);

    user.Roles.Add(role);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If the `User.Roles` collection is declared as `virtual` the line `user.Roles.Add(role);` will indeed trigger lazy loading which means that *all* roles for the user are loaded first from the database before you add the new role.

This is in fact disturbing because you don't need to load the whole `Roles` collection to add a new role to the user.

But this doesn't mean that you have to remove the `virtual` keyword and abandon lazy loading altogether. You can just turn off lazy loading in this specific situation:

```
using (var context = new MyObjectContext())
{
    context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    var user = context.Users.Single(u => u.UserId == 3);
    var role = context.Roles.Single(r => r.RoleId == 5);

    user.Roles = new List<Role>(); // necessary, if you are using POCOs
    user.Roles.Add(role);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to update the whole roles collection of a user I would prefer to load the original roles with eager loading ( = `Include`). You need this list anyway to possibly remove some roles, so you don't need to wait until lazy loading fetches them from the database:

```
var newRolsIds = new List<int> { 1, 2, 5 };
using (var context = new MyObjectContext())
{
    var user = context.Users.Include("Roles")
        .Single(u => u.UserId == 3);
    // loads user with roles, for example role 3 and 5

    var newRoles = context.Roles
        .Where(r => newRolsIds.Contains(r.RoleId))
        .ToList();

    user.Roles.Clear();
    foreach (var newRole in newRoles)
        user.Roles.Add(newRole);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Instead of loading the new roles from the database you can also attach them since you know in the example the key property value. You can also remove exactly the missing roles instead of clearing the whole collection and instead of re-adding the exisiting roles:

```
var newRolsIds = new List<int> { 1, 2, 5 };
using (var context = new MyObjectContext())
{
    var user = context.Users.Include("Roles")
        .Single(u => u.UserId == 3);
    // loads user with roles, for example role 3 and 5

    foreach (var role in user.Roles.ToList())
    {
        // Remove the roles which are not in the list of new roles
        if (!newRoleIds.Contains(role.RoleId))
            user.Roles.Remove(role);
        // Removes role 3 in the example
    }

    foreach (var newRoleId in newRoleIds)
    {
        // Add the roles which are not in the list of user's roles
        if (!user.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == newRoleId))
        {
            var newRole = new Role { RoleId = newRoleId };
            context.Roles.Attach(newRole);
            user.Roles.Add(newRole);
        }
        // Adds roles 1 and 2 in the example
    }
    // The roles which the user was already in (role 5 in the example)
    // have neither been removed nor added.

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: thx Slauma. I understood the case where I want to add a new Role to the collection user.Roles. What I can't understand is the general case where I have to manipulate a set of Roles. For example: user.Roles contains 3,5 roles; then, I choose to update user.Roles so that it contains 1,2,5 (I have to remove 3 and I have to add 1,2  in user.Roles). Does it work the same way?

Comment: After trying many different approaches I find this one to be the most versatile and mantainable

Comment: I think this is the first example of Entity Framework where it's easier to write an SQL statement. Thank you for introducing me to "Attach" function!

Comment: I guess there is a down point in this approach. When you delete the Role from Users.Roles list, it will only remove the reference in database, instead removing the record it self, which will certainly leads you to get more and more orphan records which should have been deleted.

Comment: @Slauma wow thanks for the help again! Your answers have helped me greatly twice today :D

Answer (score 1):

Slaumas answer is really good but I would like to add how you can insert a many to many relationship without loading objects from database first. If you know the Ids to connect that extra database call is redundant. The key is to use `Attach()`.

More info about Attach:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3920217/3850405

```
public class ConnectBToADto
{
    public Guid AId { get; set; }
    public Guid BId { get; set; }
}

public void ConnectBToA(ConnectBToADto dto)
{
    var b = new B() { Id = dto.BId };
    Context.B.Attach(b);

    //Add a new A if the relation does not exist. Redundant if you now that both AId and BId exists     
    var a = Context.A.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == dto.AId);
    if(a == null)
    {
        a = new A() { Id = dto.AId };
        Context.A.Add(a);
    }

    b.As.Add(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using db-first approach and automapper to map between model and entity (MVC 5) and also using eager loading.

In my scenario, there are equipments and there can be multiple users as equipment operators:

```
    public void Create()
    {
        using (var context = new INOBASEEntities())
        {
            // first i need to map model 'came from the view' to entity 
           var _ent = (Equipment)Mapper.Map(this, typeof(EquipmentModel), typeof(Equipment));

            context.Entry(_ent).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;


            // I use multiselect list on the view for operators, so i have just ids of users, i get the operator entity from user table and add them to equipment entity
            foreach(var id in OperatorIds)
            {
                AspNetUsersExtended _usr = context.AspNetUsersExtended.Where(u => u.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
                // this is operator collection
                _ent.AspNetUsersExtended2.Add(_usr);
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
            Id = _ent.Id;
        }
    }


    public void Update()
    {
        using (var context = new INOBASEEntities())
        {
            var _ent = (Equipment)Mapper.Map(this, typeof(EquipmentModel), typeof(Equipment));

            context.Entry(_ent).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;


            var parent = context.Equipment
                        .Include(x => x.AspNetUsersExtended2)//include operators
                        .Where(x => x.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
            parent.AspNetUsersExtended2.Clear(); // get the parent and clear child collection

            foreach (var id in OperatorIds)
            {
                AspNetUsersExtended _usr = context.AspNetUsersExtended.Where(u => u.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
                parent.AspNetUsersExtended2.Add(_usr);
            }

            // this line add operator list to parent entity, and also update equipment entity 
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a different question? It's hard to tell

Comment: it is the way how I create and update entities in many to many relation with ef using automapper. i think it is related with the title so maybe someone use. Is there a question above, sorry i dont understand why it is made you thought that it might be a question

Comment: It came up in the late answers review queue, where answers often should actually be new questions. It's unclear because you mention your scenario and then have a long block of code, and since the question isn't very specific (If it hadn't been posted in 2012, it would probably be closed as too broad) I couldn't tell if you were directly addressing their question. I really couldn't tell based on those things if it was meant to be an answer, but since you say it is, that's fine

Comment: actually, i faced this problem while coding and searched a solution but couldnt found a fit one. After developing a solution for my scenario, i wanted to share it with thought maybe it will be useful for someone else too.