# EF - Remove a relationship from parent entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Let's say I have two classes in my model: `Product` and `Category`.

```
public class Product
{
    public Product() {
        this.Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
    }

    [...]

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public Category() {
        this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

    [...]

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

A product has many categories and a categories apply to many products.
To model this relationship I have the following code in my `OnModelCreating` method:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasMany( p => p.Categories )
        .WithMany( p => p.Products )
        .Map( m => {
            m.MapLeftKey( "ProductID" );
            m.MapRightKey( "CategoryID" );
            m.ToTable( "CategoriesPerProduct" );
        } );
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
        .HasMany( p => p.Products )
        .WithMany( p => p.Categories )
        .Map( m => {
            m.MapLeftKey( "CategoryID" );
            m.MapRightKey( "ProductID" );
            m.ToTable( "CategoriesPerProduct" );
        } );
```

This create a new table, `CategoriesPerProduct`, which splits the M-N relationship in two 1-N relationships which is good for my needs.

I have now the requirement to update categories related to a product and, just to simplify my code, I did decided to remove all the existing categories and then adding back the new ones like in the following sample:

```
ICollection<Category> productCategories = product.Categories;
//First remove all existing categories 
foreach ( var category in productCategories ) {
    product.Categories.Remove( category );
}
// ..then add the new ones from input
foreach ( string categoryName in categories ) {
    Category c = await _ctx.Categories.SingleOrDefaultAsync( p => p.Description == categoryName );
    if ( c != null ) {
        product.Categories.Add( pc );
    }
    else {
        c = new ProductCategory() { Description = categoryName };
        _ctx.Categories.Add( c );
        await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        product.Categories.Add( c );
    }
}
await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Unfortunately, when the code hits the transaction `Commit()` method I get the following error:

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the
>   foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a
>   relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value.
>   If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship
>   must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another
>   non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Could anybody drive me in the right direction to solve this error?

Comment: This previous answer might answer your question. Seems that on one end you should do a Clear() and then add items back to the collection on that same side. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8869774/1260204

Comment: @Igor :thanks for your suggestion. I am going to try and let you know

Comment: @Igor: unfortunately this solution does not work in my case. I have modified my code to comply with the latest sample in the referenced post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited once more**

Something else that occurred to me is that you may be orphaning the other side of the relationship -- you're removing the Category entity from the Product, but are you removing the Product from that Category?  Look into WillCascadeOnDelete ([Entity Framework (EF) Code First Cascade Delete for One-to-Zero-or-One relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487577/entity-framework-ef-code-first-cascade-delete-for-one-to-zero-or-one-relations)) or try including the relationships in your queries -- instead of `_ctx.Products.Where(...)`, use `_ctx.Products.Include(p => p.Categories).Where(...)`

Let us know how that works out for you!

**Edited**

So, based on Lorenzo's response, I understand what he's trying to do.  This is something that's bit me (and probably a few people) in the past.

You're probably looking at a Cascade Delete problem -- go with option 3 (which is now not so much an option as a requirement...).

---

Take a look at [The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538974/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro)

The main issue is this (as far as I can tell since we don't know the schema of CategoriesPerProduct: our perpetrator): you're putting the entry from CategoriesPerProduct in an impossible state where it requires a Category to exist, but the Category has been effectively set to null.

Therefore, you have a few options:

1. Make the foreign key nullable (not really recommended)
2. Remove the item directly from your DbContext (something like `_ctx.Categories.Remove(category);`)
3. Mark the State as Deleted (something like `ctx.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Deleted`)

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. this make sense to me. Unfortunately, as I am creating the relationship with code, there's no direct access to the middle `CategoriesPerProduct` table. I really needs to only remove the relationship and not the Category itself because this is maybe related to other products

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting that exception because you are inserting repeated items. The repeated item is converted to `ProductCategoryID = 0`, so you get the exception.

Make these changes in your current code:

```
ICollection<Category> productCategories = product.Categories;

//Make sure that you are iterating a copy of categories, using ToList()
//If you do not use ToList() you might get an exception saying that you changed the list you are iterating

foreach ( var category in productCategories.ToList()) {
    product.Categories.Remove( category );
}

// ..then add the new ones from input
// ... but remember to add only the new ones
var currentCategories = productCategories.Select(i => i.Name);
// you could use another strategy here

foreach ( string categoryName in categories.Except(currentCategories)) {
    Category c = await _ctx.Categories.SingleOrDefaultAsync( p => p.Description == categoryName );
    if ( c != null ) {
        product.Categories.Add( pc );
    } else {
        c = new ProductCategory() { Description = categoryName };
        //_ctx.Categories.Add( c ); NOT NECESSARY - IT WILL BE AUTOMATICALLY INSERTED 
        //await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync(); NOT NECESSARY
        product.Categories.Add( c );
    }
}
```

Untested code, but it should work fine.

Hope it helps!