# Update Wizard will not add table but add new relationship

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

i search but i dont find answer.
i use ADO.NET Entity Framework,sql server. when i Update Wizard will not add table.
tables are:

*users*{UserId:primaryKey,Name,StateID:ForeignKey to *states* Table}

*states*{stateId:primaryKey,Name}

*user_state*{UserId:primaryKey,ForeignKey to *users* table,
stateId:primaryKey,ForeignKey to states table
}

i add *Users*,*sates* Tables to model successfull.
but when i update model and add *user_state* table to model,dont add and add a new  relation between state and user tables.why?what is wrong?

thank you in advanced.

Comment: There's nothing wrong. The wizard is smart enough to realize this is a many-to-many relation table, not a real entity, so it creates a many-to-many relation between the two *entities*.

Comment: ok,but how to insert row in user_state?there is a class with this name?

Comment: I think you need to check a tutorial on EF and ORMs. The classes are *not* tables. Instead of adding rows or changing foreign keys, you should be setting one object's property to the other, eg `someUser.State=someState`. Or in your case, since you have more than one state per user, add the state to the `States` property, eg `someUser.States.Add(someState);`.

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869632/entity-framework-update-many-to-many-relationship-virtual-or-not) shows how you can update a many-to-many relation.

Comment: thanks alot,that very good!