# EF: Duplicate Key on insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I Have the follwing Code:

```
public bool AddLeaveFormApprovers(List<LeaveFormApprovers> listToAdd)
{
    bool returnValue=false;
    try
    {
        using (LeaveRegulationEntities db = new LeaveRegulationEntities(ConnectionStringHelper.GetConnectionString(DaConstants.LeaveRegulationEntities)))
        {
            foreach(LeaveFormApprovers approvers in listToAdd)
            {
                approvers.AssignedLeave = db.AssignedLeave
                   .FirstOrDefault(a => a.AssignedLeaveID == approvers.AssignedLeave.AssignedLeaveID);
                approvers.LeaveFormApproverSys = db.LeaveFormApproverSys
                   .FirstOrDefault(a => a.LeaveFormApproverID == approvers.LeaveFormApproverSys.LeaveFormApproverID);
                db.LeaveFormApprovers.AddObject(approvers);
            }                    
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        returnValue = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _Exceptions.ManageExceptions(ex);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

The List of `List<LeaveFormApprovers>` is loaded from another context  for that i'm getting the objects in the current context:

```
approvers.AssignedLeave = db.AssignedLeave
    .FirstOrDefault(a => a.AssignedLeaveID == approvers.AssignedLeave.AssignedLeaveID);
approvers.LeaveFormApproverSys = db.LeaveFormApproverSys
    .FirstOrDefault(a => a.LeaveFormApproverID == approvers.LeaveFormApproverSys.LeaveFormApproverID);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_*LeaveFor*_B29C651847BE14B9'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.LeaveFormApproverSys'.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to [Attach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920111/entity-framework-4-addobject-vs-attach) approvers to this context? And then set properties?

Comment: `foreach(LeaveFormApprovers approvers in listToAdd)` -> this approvers.

Comment: You should attach the approvers to your context.

Answer (score 0):

In the query which generates `listToAdd` try appending `AsNoTracking()`. This should stop EF tracking the entity and attempting to reinsert it later.