# I can't save data using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, objectcontext

I use this code to add one item to a `SpareParts` table in my database.

```
try
{
    Database1Entities _db = new Database1Entities();

    SparePart sparePart = new SparePart();
    sparePart.manufactureID = 2;
    sparePart.name = "detail";

    _db.SpareParts.AddObject(sparePart);

    int changesNumber = _db.SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);

    int count = _db.SpareParts.Count();
    int i = 8 + 1;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

I tried `_db.SaveChanges()`. That didn't help.

I don't get any exceptions. And if I start debug 4 times, I will see count = 4. And I can iterate through all my items. But if I wait 1 minute and start debugging one more time, I see count = 1. So it seems that my changes are still not in database.

Comment: have you tried stepping thru w/ a debugger

Comment: start sql profiler and see if any insert statement is coming.

Comment: of course, and count = 4 after 4 times of starting debugging with 5 second time interval between debugging

Comment: Giedrius, how to start sql profiler

Comment: Have you read this SO article? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920111/entity-framework-4-addobject-vs-attach

Comment: I didn't find help in this article

Comment: And you're not doing *anything* different between the 4th and 5th run through? No cleaning and/or rebuilding?

Comment: Are you sure something else isn't editing the database?  Have you tried just watching the data in there directly (such as via repeated Select statements)?

Comment: Can you show us your **connection string**?

Comment: First, I do this in console application. Connection string is Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True

Comment: Refer to the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13385632/266474) I just gave you on your other SO question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add entity-framework to console application (images are included)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385013/how-to-add-entity-framework-to-console-application-images-are-included)