# Entity Framework Core in Full .Net?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

Is There Any Way To Implement Entity Framework Core In Full .Net Framework Console Application?

Comment: AFAIK EF Core supports .NET Core 1.0.1+ (or it was 1.0?) and .NET Framework 4.5.1+...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385013/how-to-add-entity-framework-to-console-application-images-are-included

Comment: you can use ef core using asp.net core with full .net framework, so I think it's something possible

Comment: yes,you can.here is the doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/full-dotnet/new-db

Comment: @Sampath The link you have provided is for using `EF Core` on `.NET Core` (not on Full .NET Framework app).

Comment: @NikxDa How the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13385013/1232087) you provided is related to `EF Core`? That link is about using `EF` and not `EF Core`.

Comment: @nam This thread is 3.5 years old, so I am not sure that it matters a lot anymore

Answer (score 5):

First you need to create console application with full .net framework,
Second install these packages using package manager console,

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools –Pre
```

Now you need to create your model and context

```
namespace ConsoleEfCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyContext db = new MyContext();
            db.Users.Add(new User { Name = "Ali" });
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

then just need to use this command

```
Add-Migration initial
```

and then you need to update your database to create that

```
Update-Database
```

run project and you we'll see User would insert to your database

Comment: It doesn't work for me. install-package. I got this error : `Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a 
project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible 
with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

Comment: it seems `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` 1.1.5 or lower support .NET 4.5+, but the EF 2.0.0+ is not supported.

Comment: In the example code, the connection string is hard-coded. Is there a way to direct EFCore to read from a configuration file when creating a migration?

Comment: EF-Core 3x is compiled based on .NET Standard 2.0 and is compatible with .NET 4.8. But EF-Core 5x is compiled based on .NET Standard 2.1 and it's not compatible with .NET 4x anymore: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/859