# No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef" error in a project without project.json file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsto, entity-framework-core

I've a [VSTO - AddIn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620922.aspx) project developed using `VS2015-Update3`. I'm trying to [implement a Database functionality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404815.aspx) in the project and for that I'm implementing **EF Core**. I'm  using the following official [MSDN tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite). But I'm getting the above error when I run the command `dotnet ef migrations add MyFirstMigration`.

**Please Note**:

1. VSTO-AddIn projects do not have a project.json file.
2. VSTO projects use Full .NET framework (I'm using .NET 4.6.2). But, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716588/entity-framework-core-in-full-net), one can use EF Core in a Full .NET framework.

Comment: 1) What is your dotnet SDK version (run `dotnet --version`)? 2) Do you have `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` package installed/added to project (and what version)?

Comment: @Dmitry 1) dotnet SDK version is: `1.0.0-preview2-003131` 2) I get the error: `Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools'`

Comment: Lack of package is reason for error. You need `...Tools` package for [package manager commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell) or `...Tools.DotNet` to run `dotnet ef ...` from command line. Check you package source configuration - both packages [are listed on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools)

Comment: @Dmitry Is there something from your link for [package manager commands] they I need to install. Because I get the same error as above when trying to install `...Tools.DotNet` or `....Tools`.

Comment: You need at least one of this packages - they contains migration tools you ask for. You need to solve problem "Unable to find..." in your project, because this packages are listed on NuGet.