# MVC 4 - Entity Framework, ViewModel and Object Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework with MVC 4 to develop a web application. I'm also using a ViewModel named VehicleTypeViewModel which is created like this :

```
public class VehicleTypeViewModel
{
    public VehicleType VehicleType { get; set; }

    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Zàéèêçñ\s][a-zA-Zàéèêçñ\s-]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid name !")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 300)]
    public int CO2 { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> ProductCompanies { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> MotorTypes { get; set; }
}
```

In my Edit Action, everything's good but one thing : when I debug, arriving to the `db.Attach(...)` step, my app throws an exception which says :

```
The object cannot be attached because it is already in the object context. An object can only be reattached when it is in an unchanged state.
```

Here are my post action :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(VehicleTypeViewModel vtvm)
{
    ViewBag.Id_VehicleMotorType = new SelectList(db.VehicleMotorTypes, "Id_VehicleMotorType", "Name", vtvm.VehicleType.Id_VehicleMotorType);
    ViewBag.Id_ProductCompany = new SelectList(db.ProductCompanies, "Id_ProductCompany", "Name", vtvm.ProductType.Id_ProductCompany);

    vtvm.ProductCompanies = db.ProductCompanies.ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.Name, Value = c.Id_ProductCompany.ToString() }).ToList();
    vtvm.MotorTypes = db.VehicleMotorTypes.ToList().Select(v => new SelectListItem { Text = v.Name, Value = v.Id_VehicleMotorType.ToString() }).ToList();

    VehicleType vehicleType = db.VehicleTypes.Single(v => v.Id_VehicleType == vtvm.VehicleType.Id_VehicleType);
    ProductType productType = db.ProductTypes.Single(p => p.Id_ProductType == vtvm.ProductType.Id_ProductType);
    VehicleMotorType vehicleMotorType = null;

    ModelStateDictionary errors = Validator.isValid(vtvm.ProductType);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (errors.Count > 0)
        {
            ModelState.Merge(errors);
            return View(vtvm);
        }

        productType.Model = vtvm.ProductType.Model;
        productType.CatalogPrice = vtvm.ProductType.CatalogPrice;
        productType.Id_ProductCompany = vtvm.ProductType.Id_ProductCompany;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vtvm.Name) && (vtvm.CO2 > 0))
        {
            vehicleMotorType = new VehicleMotorType()
            {
                CO2 = vtvm.CO2,
                Name = vtvm.Name
            };

            vehicleType.CO2 = vtvm.VehicleType.CO2;
            vehicleType.VehicleMotorType = vehicleMotorType;
            vehicleType.Id_ProductType = vtvm.ProductType.Id_ProductType;
        }
        else
        {
            vehicleType.CO2 = vtvm.VehicleType.CO2;
            vehicleType.Id_ProductType = vtvm.ProductType.Id_ProductType;
            vehicleType.Id_VehicleMotorType = vtvm.VehicleType.Id_VehicleMotorType;
        }

        db.VehicleTypes.Attach(vehicleType);
        db.ProductTypes.Attach(productType);

        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(vehicleType, EntityState.Modified);
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(productType, EntityState.Modified);

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(vtvm);
}
```

I have no idea why I'm dealing with this kind of error. Any idea to solve this please?

Comment: You are retrieving the entities from the db, so when you change them there is no need to attach them again. Just call `SaveChanges`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traffy,

Short answer, you should remove this 2 lines

```
 db.VehicleTypes.Attach(vehicleType);
 db.ProductTypes.Attach(productType);
```

When you retrieve any entity from an EntityFramework instance and modifies any property the Entity Framework is tracking the changes automatically.

To apply the changes to the database you just need to call

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

To understand better when to use Add and Attach methods you should read this
[Entity Framework 4 - AddObject vs Attach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920111/entity-framework-4-addobject-vs-attach).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "Attach" as the object is already in the database, no need to attach again, just alter the state and save changes

```
 var comp = (from com in db.tbl_CompGroup where com.Group_Id == GroupID select com).FirstOrDefault();

        comp.Survey_Est = surveyPost.Survey_Est;

        //db.tbl_CompGroup.Attach(comp);
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(comp, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
        db.SaveChanges();
```