# Adding new record in a related table in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I want to add new records to an related table. I got three tables:
[image]

I want to add new technical_skill_value to that table.
This is my code right now:

```
        using (var db = new KnowItCvdbEntities())
        {
            var dbSkill = new TECHNICAL_SKILLS_VALUES
            {
                technical_skill_value_id = new Random().Next(),
                skill_name = TextBoxTechSkill.Text,
                skill_type = DropDownListTechSkill.SelectedItem.Text
            };

            //I want to add the new skill to my TECHNICAL_SKILLS_VALUE table. But I really don't get it how to make it.     
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: And? What is your question?

Comment: @DavidJashi, How to add the new skill to that specific table. db.TECHNICAL_SKILLS_VALUES doesn't give me an ADD function

Comment: @DavidJashi, And i wrote my question in the comented code, did u even read whole question?

Comment: Well, this is not quite how we ask questions here, when we want to get an answer.

Comment: @DavidJashi, My bad then, but back to the topic. How do i save the values? As i said, db.TECHNICAL_SKILLS_VALUES doesn't give me an add function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line before `db.SaveChanges();`

```
db.TECHNICAL_SKILLS_VALUES.Add(dbSkill);
```

OR

```
db.AddToTECHNICAL_SKILLS_VALUES(dbSkill);
```

Comment: db.TECHNICAL_SKILLS_VALUES doesn't give me an add function :(

Comment: I've added another option. But both option usually available to use!

Comment: if none of the options works for you, then you have some other problem in initiating db, i guess

Comment: The second option worked, didn't even notice that there were an AddToTECHNICAL_SKILLS_VALUES function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is an issue surrounding your naming... e.g. an entity for people would be named Person, the entity set would be called Persons. Yet in your code you create a new entity set and not a new entity (according to naming).

Notice the pluralisation... your actually creating an entity set?

I would expect something more along the lines of:

```
        TECHNICAL_SKILLS_VALUE dbSkill = new TECHNICAL_SKILLS_VALUE
        {
            technical_skill_value_id = new Random().Next(),
            skill_name = TextBoxTechSkill.Text,
            skill_type = DropDownListTechSkill.SelectedItem.Text
        };

        db.AddToTECHNICAL_SKILLS_VALUES(dbSkill) 
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Try:

```
db.AddToTECHNICAL_SKILLS_VALUES(dbSkill);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Try to attach the object:

```
db.TECHNICAL_SKILLS_VALUES.AddObject(dbSkill);
db.SaveChanges();
```

read this for reference and examples : [clicky link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920111/entity-framework-4-addobject-vs-attach)

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the answer, db.AddToTECHNICAL_SKILLS_VALUES(dbSkill); worked fine, but sarvar026 above you provide the answer. Thanks!