# C# ASP.NET MVC Code First Not Saving Changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ninject

I have a really simple model:

```
public class Item : DbEntity
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Quantity {get;set;}
    public virtual Category Category {get;set;}
}

public class Category : DbEntity
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I use the below methods to save and commit changes to the database:

```
public void SaveEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : DbEntity
{
    if (entity.Id.Equals(Guid.Empty))
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    else
        _context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

    _context.SaveChanges();
}

public void DeleteEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : DbEntity
{
     _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
     _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

These save and delete methods reside in the Repository, this Repository is Ninjected, so it should have a constant state throughout the application life. This is a tried and tested method, it has always worked for me. Now for some reason when I do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MenuItemViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // TODO: Add ViewModel Logic
        vm.MenuItem.Category = _repository.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(vm.SelectedCategory));

    try
    {
        // TODO: Add Save Logic
            _repository.SaveEntity(vm.MenuItem);

            TempData["success"] = true;
            TempData["message"] = String.Format("Saved {0} Successfully", vm.MenuItem.Description);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
             TempData["error"] = true;
             TempData["message"] = "Error Occured";
    }

    return _redirectTo;
    }

    return View("Shape", vm);
}
```

The view part is simple, just some fields for the `Name` and `Quantity`, the `Category` is a `Drop Down` box containing all the category names as `Text` and id as `Value`, this gets posted back to the server where it the repository goes and collects the new `Category` and assigns it to the entity.

For some reason this just doesn't commit any changes to the database, break pointed before and after, when I breaked after I checked the database, it hadn't changed!

Can anyone see the silly little mistake that is preventing it from updating.

***EDIT***

Just read this [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920111/entity-framework-4-addobject-vs-attach), I picked up on the part where is says, you attach it first then edit it, because when attach is called, you call it with `Unchanged` state, then when you modify it, the changes will be saved when you call `SaveChanges()`.

Has this got anything to do with it?!

***UPDATE***
Okay some interesting news, I step through the `SaveEntity` method, after i step past the `SaveChanges()` I check the context again, it shows that it has been updated?! Could the fact that I redirect to another controller and action be affecting the results or table modification? I don't think the issue is with in the `SaveEntity` method!!

***LATEST UPDATE***

I changed the model of the `Item` and simply added the line `public Guid CategoryId {get;set;}` which simply changes the `Category` to turn on `Cascade On Delete`. Now I get this error when I try and `SaveChanges`:

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to use `DbContext.Attach` before calling `DbContext.Entry(object)`?

Comment: The repository when it gets called by ninject instantiates the Context. So it should already be there??

Comment: I am definitely sure that Ninject will NOT go about attaching objects to your DbContext.

Comment: Sorry man...worth a shot...

Comment: yeah no problem, definitely worth a shot!

Comment: _repository.SaveEntity(vm.MenuItem);

I assume inside that function, you should attach the entity

Comment: Are you injecting a new context `.InRequestScope()` ?

Comment: I just do `_ninjectKernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to fix this I changed the `Item` entity to:

```
public class Item : DbEntity
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Quantity {get;set;}

    public Guid? CategoryId {get;set;}
    public virtual Category Category {get;set;}
}
```

This basically, makes it easier and quicker to change the `Category` because you don't have to make another call to the database. the `?` makes this a nullable property which sets `Cascade Delete` to `No Action` so that when you delete an `Item` it doesn't annoyingly go off and delete the associated `Categories`.

I still have no idea why the original way doesn't work, it has done in the past and it used to negate having to put `public Guid? CategoryId {get;set;}` because it would set the nullable property and would already create a `Category_Id` field. But hey ho, that's the way it wants to be, then I'll play ball!!

Answer (score 0):

In SaveEntity, if the Id doesn't equal Guid.Empty, you are not attaching the item to the context, only setting the State to Modified. Try:

```
public void SaveEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : DbEntity
{
    if (entity.Id.Equals(Guid.Empty))
    {
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity); // Automatically sets state to Added
    }
    else 
    {
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
        _context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Also, for DeleteEntity, try Attach and Remove:

```
public void DeleteEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : DbEntity
{
    _context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity); // Attaches entity with state Unchanged
    _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity); // Changes entity state to Deleted
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The key is that in a disconnected environment such as ASP.NET, the model returning from a post is not attached to the context and as such needs to be reattached before it can be processed.

As a test, check the state of the entity in your existing code, before SaveChanges is called, and it is likely Unchanged meaning no action will be taken on it.

Comment: how do you find in debug using intellisense the state of the entity? or should i just put a line in asking for its state?

Comment: I put a line in, `var entryState = _context.Entry(entity).State;` it says `Modified`, I never have had to attach, it has always worked, that is the weird thing!

Comment: You can set a breakpoint and hover the mouse over the variable (entity) when the breakpoint is hit.