# EF ComboBox not displaying SelectedItem Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am using Entity Framework and Caliburn.Micro to implement an MVVM application.

Basically, I have set up AuthorModel and BookModel in a one to many relationship - an Author having multiple Books and a Book having only a single Author.

I have a SelectBookWindow where I use DbContext to load `ObservableCollection<Book>`, from where I select a Book I want to view/edit. I then pass the selected Book as a parameter to an EditBookWindow where I have a combobox enumerating all the Authors but with the current Author selected.

In here, I load up `ObservableCollection<Author>` using a different instance of DbContext and set it as the combobox's `ItemsSource` and as well as do `SelectedItem="{Binding Author}"`. (`Author` being a virtual property of `Book`)

The ComboBox displays the Author list correctly. However, it doesn't seem to display the Book's Author as its SelectedItem.

Is this because I am using a different instance of DbContext?  If so, how can I rectify this problem?

Comment: You can pass the context to the second window along with the selected book, though i'm not certain it's the best idea...

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. Because the author in ItemsSource is referencing to a different object although the content is the same as the one that is bind to SelectedItem.

I don't know much about EF, I guess you can use the same context for the two entities. Or override the equals (and gethashcode) of the Author class to compare the content then return true if the same.

Answer (score 1):

As Eben mentions, the `Author` referenced by the `ItemsSource` will be a different object (although it happens to reference the same entity).

I think your approach of using a new `DbContext` for both of your windows is correct, you can run into problems if you have persisting/shared `DbContexts`; it makes sense to load an `EditWindow` with a new context, perform your edits, and dispose of the context.

One option is to `Detach` your `Book` entity from  the old `DbContext`, and `Attach` it to your new context: (a good explanation here [Entity Framework 4 - AddObject vs Attach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920111/entity-framework-4-addobject-vs-attach)).

I would probably just favour using the passed `Book` entity to reload the selected `Book` from the new context e.g. using [`DbSet<TEntity>.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), and using that retrieved entity to bind to the `SelectedItem` (rather than the one you're passing across windows).