# copying one objects data to other?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I need to update EF record, in method I have EF object and another new objct which I want to use to update data from. But I m not sure how to copy data from new object to existing one.

Help please.
Here is my code:

```
public int   PostHomeLead(string _lead)
   {

       try
       {
           int result = 0;
           Lead lead = new Lead();
           lead = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Lead>(_lead);

           //check if lead exist with same session id, if so update it other wise add new.
           Lead existingLead = new Lead();
           existingLead = db2.HomeLoanCustRepo.GetByID(lead.Lead_id);

           if (existingLead == null)
           {
               db2.HomeLoanCustRepo.Insert(lead);
               db2.Save();
               result = 1;
           }
           else
           {                   
               db2.HomeLoanCustRepo.Update(lead);
               db2.Save();
               result = 1;
           }
           return result;           
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }

   }
```

Comment: And what specific problem are you having with your code?

Comment: @Servy what I asked is how to copy one object data to other.

Answer (score 1):

Either map the properties manually:

```
existingLead.Foo = deserializedLead.Foo;
existingLead.Bar = deserializedLead.Bar;
existingLead.Baz = deserializedLead.Baz;
```

Or use a library that does this, like AutoMapper.

As for your comment, [creating a deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects) is what you seem to be after. Note this allows for [overposting or mass assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_assignment_vulnerability) when you don't verify which properties may be updated. You'll need to [`Attach()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920111/entity-framework-4-addobject-vs-attach) the cloned object when using cloning or mapping, as it will not be the same object as returned by `GetByID()`, so Entity Framework's change tracker won't recognize it.

Comment: is it possible using linq or lambda or any out of box class/ library of .net ?

Comment: thanks, I m using Attach() but it throw error something primary key is aleady used by another object. Kindly help me what would be solution.

Comment: The solution would be searching the web and this site for the actual error you receive and applying what you've learned from what you've read there. I'm sorry, but I don't do [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). A last hint: your error is caused by first calling `GetByID()`, which pulls that entity into the change tracker, and using the same context trying to save _another_ entity with the same ID. You need to make that `GetByID()` query `.AsNoTracking()`.