# Entity Framework related entities on object is not updated

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Whenever I try to change Department and Position objects of the Employee class they are not updating inside database on the Employee entity. For example, I want to change employee Position from junior (id - 1, name of the position - junior) to middle (id - 2, name of the position - middle). But, whenever I try to save this changes to the database they don't apply.

My Employee entity

```
    public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public EmployeePosition Position { get; set; }
    public string Head { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    {
        Department = new Department();
        Position = new EmployeePosition();
    }
}
```

EmployeePosition entity

```
    public class EmployeePosition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My modify employee method in ViewModel

```
        public void ModifyEmployee(int id)
    {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.GetEmployee(id);
        using (var context = new PowerCoEntity())
        {
            employee.Position = context.EmployeePositions.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == SelectedPositionId);
            employee.Department = context.Deprtments.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DepartmentId == SelectedDepartmentId);
            if (SelectedHeadId != null)
                employee.Head = employeeRepository.GetHeadName(SelectedHeadId.Value);
            else employee.Head = "";
        }

        employee.Salary = Employee.Salary;
        employee.FullName = Employee.FullName;

        employeeRepository.ModifyEmployee(employee);
    }
```

Modify method in the context class

```
 public void ModifyEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        using (var context = new PowerCoEntity())
        {
            context.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 1**

I got it working by changing ModifyEmployee methods in the ViewModel and Context class. But I need to pass all the parameters through method now. How can I be able to use different contexts to modify object?
Context class:

```
public void ModifyEmployee(int id, int selectedPositionId, int selectedDepartmentId, int? selectedHeadId, Employee employee)
    {
        using (var context = new PowerCoEntity())
        {
            Employee emp = context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e=> e.EmployeeId == 32);
            emp.Salary = employee.Salary;
            emp.FullName = employee.FullName;
            emp.Department = employee.Department;
            emp.Position = context.EmployeePositions.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == selectedPositionId);
            emp.Department = context.Deprtments.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DepartmentId == selectedDepartmentId);
            if (selectedHeadId != null)
                emp.Head = GetHeadName(selectedHeadId.Value);
            else emp.Head = "";

            emp.Salary = employee.Salary;
            emp.FullName = employee.FullName;
            context.Entry(emp).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
        public void ModifyEmployee(int id)
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();

        employee.Salary = Employee.Salary;
        employee.FullName = Employee.FullName;

        employeeRepository.ModifyEmployee(id, SelectedPositionId, SelectedDepartmentId, SelectedHeadId, employee);
    }
```

Comment: You are using two different instances of context. And you are not changing state of department entity. You have changed only employee state

Comment: @Gek:: Is it updating other columns except position ?

Comment: Yes, it's not updating only complex Objects - Position, Department. I got it working moving all to one context. But, can I somehow do it with my approach?

Comment: You need to understand how to work with a context better.  Putting the ModifyEmployee function in the context doesn't gain you anything and is likely making this task harder than it needs to be.  If you absolutely need to manage objects between contexts look into the Attach() function:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3920217/3384612